# SSRS Matrix column group split on another page if threshold column number crossed

Tags: c#, reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

1)I am using matrix to show my data as tax for each year. So in row I am showing tax name and for column I am grouping against year. I using rdlc to export it as pdf. on a page as per width it showing 6 column and as there is no space it split remaining columns on another page. Now my issue is, there are no much rows and there is space on same page below that tablix to occupy another tablix (splitted column's) still it is moving remaining columns on another page. I tried with keepTogether property but is it not working for me. I set it for tablix,column group also.

2) Now I want to use this above report as sub report so I add this report on another report file at the end of page. So while rendering the report as subreport it split exceed columns on another page which is also at the end of page keeping a lot of empty space at start of that second page. How can I avoid this.

### Suppose I have Main report with some basic info at first then I put sub report at end of first page. Now sub report contains data in matrix which column increases dynamically. so after 4 column it split and goes on next page for next page and put remaining columns on next page at the END. Which I want at the start of next page.

---

basic info

---

sub report content in matrix

### ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

page break here from sub report as more columns are there.

---

( this space remain blank. I want to avoid this blank space.)

---

sub report remaining columns came here.

---

Comment: Hi. Can you upload and show you Output and Design View ?

Comment: Hi Chanom because my reputation is below 10 it is not allowing me to add images

Comment: Hi Sachin. Can you upload them to imgur maybe and simply post the URL?

Comment: Hi Dan, I dont have access to imgur so I will edit my question with more details in text only..